# Style Radio Group Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want ask how to we can design Radio Group in Android like this picture

[image: My Radio Button] "My Style"

I'm design XML like this :

```
    <RadioGroup
       android:layout_below="@+id/btnGroup"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdiEasy"
               android:text="EASY"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdiMedium"
               android:text="MEDIUM"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </RelativeLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdiHard"
               android:text="HARD"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <RadioButton
               android:id="@+id/rdiHardest"
               android:text="HARDEST"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </RelativeLayout>
   </RadioGroup>
```

I'm use RadioButtonGroup wrap 2 RelativeLayout , each RelativeLayout contain two Radio Button. But with this design , i can't choose only one Radio Button , still can choose multi radio button. So anyone can help me how to design Radio Button with this design but just only choose one option.

Comment: use two LinearLayout (horizontal) within LinearLayout with orientation vertical instead of Relative layout.

Comment: For Your Information RadioGroup should contains  RadioButton Only

Comment: Thanks for reply , i mean i have proplem with choice mode of RadioGroup !  With my code i can implement this design but can't only choose one option (Radio Button Group not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you

https://gist.github.com/ishitcno1/9544243

Comment: I can implement this design , i just have proplem with RadioButtonGroup. I can't choose only one option. Still can choose multi option

Comment: Hey EddyLee I changed my code & it works me please check it out for same Now it will choose only one radio

Comment: Yes i saw your code , but still have proplem : You have two RadioButtonGroup ; I need JUST ONE radio button group because i want to only select 1/4 option

Comment: Yes ! That's extractly

Comment: Hey EddyLee Check out this link which will exactly fulfill your requirement

Comment: Thanks ! If don't have way do that with XML so we need to code :( Thanks again Mohit Trivedi

Comment: Vote answer if you got your solution

Comment: With your solution , if i have 2 radio button in row 1 and 2 radio button in row 2 , so i can't align left-right for it

Comment: within the help of layouts and styles you will able to do this & In addition you can also use Linear Layout instead of relative

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it work perfect.

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:transitionGroup="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdiEasy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Easy" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdiHard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hard" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdiMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rdiEasy"
                android:text="Medium" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rdiHardest"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rdiHard"
                android:text="Hardest" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: With your code still have proplem . i still can choose both 4 option of Radio

Comment: here getting problem due to linear layout.I will update u soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code without using layouts inside radiogroup.and try to achieve the desired pattern by setting gravity,like this and check if radio button is selected only one or multiple

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_weight=".07"
    android:gravity="center">


    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="New RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="New RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="New RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="New RadioButton" />

</RadioGroup>
```